# How to get the clicked column on TDBGrid.DblClick(Sender: TObject)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

When using the OnDblClick event of a TDBGrid, how can i know what column was double clicked ?

This is easy with the OnCellClick as it has a TColumn parameter, but not on OnDblClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnDblClick` event doesn't give you *any* information about the click, in particular where the click was performed, let alone which grid cell was clicked on. So, you will have to determine that information manually.

Try this:

- Get the current mouse position within the grid, by passing `Mouse.CursorPos` to `TDBGrid.ScreenToClient()`
- Then, use `TDBGrid.MouseCoord()` to determine the row/column indexes of the cell that is underneath the mouse.
- Then, check if the cell row/column corresponds to a data cell, and if so then use the `TDBGrid.SelectedIndex` property to index into the `TDBGrid.Columns` property.

This is basically the same thing that `TDBGrid` does internally when firing the `OnCellClick` event, only it does this in response to a `MouseUp` event, which provides the mouse coordinates within the grid, thus skipping the 1st step above.

For example:

```pascal
type
  TDBGridAccess = class(TDBGrid)
  end;

procedure TMyForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TitleOffset: Byte;
  Pt: TPoint;
  Cell: TGridCoord;
  Column: TColumn;
begin
  TitleOffset := Ord(dgTitles in DBGrid1.Options);
  Pt := DBGrid1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Cell := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  if (Cell.X >= TDBGridAccess(DBGrid1).IndicatorOffset) and (Cell.Y >= TitleOffset) then
  begin
    Column := DBGrid1.Columns[DBGrid1.SelectedIndex];
    // use Column as needed...
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: based on @UweRaabe's comments, you should be able to just use `TDBGrid.SelectedIndex` by itself:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
begin
  Index := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex;
  if (Index <> -1) then
  begin
    Column := DBGrid1.Columns[Index];
    // use Column as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i'm getting '[dcc32 Error] : E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TCustomDBGrid.IndicatorOffset' . I'm on Delphi 11.0, any ideas please ?

Comment: You can use an accessor class to reach `protected` members.  I have updated my example to show this.

Comment: Awesome Remy, thanks !

Comment: @UweRaabe `TDBGrid` does not derive from `TCustomDrawGrid`

Comment: @UweRaabe "*OK, then you can use MouseCoord*" - um, do you not see me using it in my example above?

Answer (score 3):

During *TDBGrid.OnDblClick* the dataset is positioned to the clicked record and the column can be retrieved with the *TDBGrid.SelectedIndex* property. If you are interested in the underlying dataset field, you can directly access it with *TDBGrid.SelectedField*.

Comment: Are you sure? When I look at `TDBGrid`'s source code, it looks like the `OnDblClick` event is fired (in `TCustomDBGrid.MouseDown()` when `ssDouble` is in `Shift`) before the dataset is updated. Unless the active record is updated on the 1st mouse down, before the 2nd mouse down then fires the event? I guess that would make sense.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the first click selects the record and column. You can see that when you set a breakpoint in MouseDown with a counter value of 2.